# Change default screenshot utility

Tags: release-freya, screenshot

Currently elementary OS Freya uses `gnome-screenshot` as its default screenshot utility.

This has an annoying bug were screenshots of active windows will show the background around the border.

I've found that [screenshot-tool](https://launchpad.net/screenshot-tool), an app built for elementary OS, solves this while integrating nicely with the system.

How can I change the default application that launches when <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> is pressed, from `gnome-screenshot` to `screenshot-tool`?

---

To install `screenshot-tool` you can add its PPA, as instructed in the [elementary-apps](https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Screenshot/) blog:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fabiozaramella/screenshot-tool && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screenshot-tool
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a new keyboard shortcut:

First, open system settings and click keyboard:

[image]

Chose Custom, in the sidebar

[image]

Click the + button

[image]

Enter your command - in this case `screenshot-tool`

[image]

Click "Disabled", then press your chosen shortcut (in this case <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd>). You will have to accept it disabling the old shortcut, and then it will show up:

[image]

Finally, you have to log out and back in for the shortcut to be active.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim, but I already know how to set a custom keyboard shortcut. I asked how can I use the *default* shortcut to take a screenshot but re-direct it to this application instead of `gnome-screenshot`.

Comment: @Gabriel by reassigning the shortcut to the new application will do exactly that.

Comment: @Gabriel You can use PrtScrn as the new shortcut - for screenshot-tool. As it is the same key, you won't have to change what you press

Comment: @Gabriel - when you select the PrtScrn for the new program, you will be asked if you want to re-assign the shortkey

Comment: So with custom shortcut assigned, its will disable the previous one, right?

Comment: @FerriSutanto yes

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `gnome-screenshot` command run `screenshot-tool`.

First, make a new file in your home area, called `.bash_aliases`, and edit it.

```
touch .bash_aliases
scratch-text-editor .bash_aliases
```

Then into it put the following:

```
alias gnome-screenshot='screenshot-tool'
```

and save it.

I'm not sure the system settings will listen to this however.

Answer (score -1):

You can change what the binary `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot` points to.

First, rename it:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo mv gnome-screenshot gnome-screenshot-old
```

Then create a link from `screenshot` (the executable for `screenshot-tool`) to `gnome-screenshot`:

```
sudo ln -s screenshot gnome-screenshot
```

now when you run the command `gnome-screenshot` it will open `screenshot-tool`.

---

Note, however, that the shortcut PrtScrn *may* be assigned to `gnome-screenshot -w` (or with some option). It probably isn't, but if it is it will cause this solution to fail.

Comment: You would need to repeat this procedure after each gnome-screenshot update.